# How to call public function from event handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class in JavaScript called Greeter. Inside my class I have:

- a constructor
- a document click event handler
- a public function called `a`

What I want is for my document click event handler to call the public function `a`. But I get the error: "*Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined*"

This is my code:

```
var Greeter = (function () {

    function Greeter() {
    }

    Greeter.prototype.a = function () {
        alert('I am in a');
    };

    $(document).on( "click", function() {
        alert('I am in click event handler');
        a(); // <-- Why can't I call the public function a
    });

    return Greeter;
})();

var greeter = new Greeter();
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ffwr3g0m/5/).

Comment: Just as an aside, you are making your code needlessly confusing. What is the purpose of the IIFE? Also, in contrast to the answer provided, and without seeing the real code you intend to write, you will probably want `this.a()` to invoke it, as I am assuming you want `a` to be operating on the instance, as opposed to the "static" method (as a Java person would say it).

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if I could invoke it on the instance like this.a().

Comment: In this context, `a` is a property of `Greeter`. As such, the function `a()` doesn't exist without an instance of `Greeter`. In your example your trying to call `a()` before `Greeter` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is not a *public* function here. The functions which are defined on `window` object are public and can be access from anywhere(using *scope chain*). It is defined on the prototype of `Greeter` so, the objects created on Greeter using `new Greeter` or children inherited from Greeter can call it using the syntax `obj.a()`.

You can call the function using the following syntax

```
Greeter.prototype.a();
```

Or, you can also access it by using the `greeter` object created from `Greeter`

```
greeter.a(); // instance of Greeter class. Has access to the function defined on prototype
```

I'd also recommend to move the code of adding new function on prototype and event binding outside of the `Greeter` function.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z91rqjx7/)

```js
var Greeter = (function() {
  function Greeter() {}

  return Greeter;
})();

Greeter.prototype.a = function() {
  alert('I am in a');
  // b();
};

$(document).on("click", function() {
  alert('I am in click event handler');
  Greeter.prototype.a();
});

var greeter = new Greeter();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or `greeter.a()` if he wants to use the `Greeter` created on the last line.

Comment: @Paulpro Yes, I've mentioned it `the objects created on Greeter using new Greeter or children inherited from Greeter can call it using the syntax obj.a().`

Comment: @Tushar Could also set `a` with `Greeter.prototype.a = a = function () {}; $(document).on( "click", function() {a();});` http://jsfiddle.net/ffwr3g0m/9/

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, that can be done, but then there is not point in using `prototypal inheritance` :). That would defy the purpose of prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

What you most likely want (I am guessing here)

```
var Greeter = (function () {

    function Greeter() {
        var _this = this;
        $(document).on( "click", function() {
             alert('I am in click event handler');
             _this.a(); // <-- Why can't I call the public function a
        });
     }

     Greeter.prototype.a = function () {
         alert('I am in a');
     };



     return Greeter;
})();

var greeter = new Greeter();
```

This way, the handler is only called once you instantiate. 
and it has a real reference to a.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks :-)